# Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'buildProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException

Tags: maven, spring-boot

```
             <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>build-info</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-info</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

this the main class

```
public class GetSpaOsmiumVersionClient implements CommandLineRunner{

@Autowired
BuildProperties buildProperties;

public static void main( String[] args ){
     SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(GetSpaOsmiumVersionClient.class);
     app.setBannerMode(Banner.Mode.OFF);
     app.run(args);
    }

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

      Options options = new Options();
      options.addOption("h", "help", false, "prints the help content");
      options.addOption("v", "version", false, "version spa osmium");
      
      try{
          //Etape 2: Analyse de la ligne de commande
          CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();
          CommandLine commandLine = parser.parse(options, args);
          
          if(commandLine.hasOption("v")){
              buildProperties.getVersion(); 
          }else {
                 HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
                 formatter.printHelp( "App" , options );
                 System.exit(1);
          
       }
```

Comment: It is not clear what the question is. It will help you get an answer if you read first [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). For example, start by cleaning the formatting...

Comment: i want to show the version project in command line but i have this error

Answer (score 3):

Found this question in Google Search for a similar issue, so I'll leave this answer so other fellow developers can save some time.

The error message in the question title

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'buildProperties'
```

is often caused by a misunderstanding on how the property `BuildProperties` works.

Basically, `BuildProperties` only works if we have executed the 'build-info' goal of Maven Spring Boot Plugin (aka, run the following command in `cmd`):

```
mvn spring-boot:build-info
```

The reason is that BuildProperties is NOT something built-in, but a product of that Maven goal. When that goal is executed, a file build-info.properties is generated - and the code will read from that file.

Usually Maven project is set up so that it will automatically execute that goal on pipeline (in `plugins` part, see picture below). However when we trigger a run on local IDE, that goal isn't automatically executed, hence the problem.

[image]

Detailed explanation on how it works can be found in this reference:
https://www.vojtechruzicka.com/spring-boot-version/

**If you prefer to work with IDE** (eg: IntelliJ) instead of command line, you might find Maven tool window. Your job is to "run" the "build-info" goal before starting the server.

Example for IntelliJ: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-goals.html

Comment: Thanks!  Not being a full time spring-boot developer this was helpful to explain why two nearly identical applications had different results.